# Delete a file downloaded by exo player download service

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exo player download service to download video files in my android application. So far so good as downloading is very smooth and it provides forground notification also. Problem is with the deleting completed download as we are providing a feature for user to delete the file in the future if he wants. 
I didn't find any method to do so in download service and exoplayer is using some complex file structure to store the downloaded media file.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It provides some feature for removing downloads: https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html#removing-downloads

Comment: It only removes the download in progress.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example [DownloadService](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/offline/DownloadService.html#sendRemoveDownload-android.content.Context-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-boolean-)'s:

```
DownloadService.sendRemoveDownload(context, MyDownloadService.class, download.request.id, false);
```

or [DownloadManager](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/offline/DownloadManager.html#removeDownload-java.lang.String-)'s

```
removeDownload(String id)
```

method.